# How to generate a domain with www from user's input?

Tags: bash, lets-encrypt

The user will input a domain name, don't know has www or not. The end result should be `-d domain.com -d www.domain.com`

Hereby is my trying, but failed:

```
letsdomain=""
if [ ! -z "${server_names}" ]; then
    for i in ${server_names}
    do
       letsdomain=${letsdomain}" -d ${i}"
    done
fi
```

I am trying to get a Lets Encrypt ssl certificate that works for both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` by following command. Thanks.

```
echo "Starting create Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate..."
    /bin/certbot certonly --email ${email} --agree-tos -n --webroot -w ${website_root} ${letsdomain}
```

Comment: and this is tagged with "PHP" because of...?

Comment: corrected, it's bash not php. thanks.

Comment: i think that's what you are looking for https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-for-www-and-non-www/23965/4

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm looking for. I want to automatic the whole issue process, create a bash file, when it's running it will prompt user to input the domain name, and the bash will generate '-d domain.com -d www.domain.com' based on the input.

Comment: See [Let's Encrypt - Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Let%E2%80%99s_Encrypt)  (you can separate the domain and sub-domain in a comma-separated-list or with multiple `-d` options).

Comment: Yes but that's what I asked for. thanks.